# Beautiful Soup не корректно читает xml файл

Tags: python, xml, beautiful-soup

Есть такой кусок кода. Для аналогичного файла работает великолепно, но в одном конкретном не правильно разбивает xml по тегам.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_bd():
    styles = []
    path = 'C:\\Users\\dfusd\\PycharmProjects\\dance_parse\\DB_demo\\'
    files = ['Group.xml', 'Teacher.xml', 'Style.xml']
    file = open(path + files[1], encoding='utf8')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(file, features="lxml")
    i = 0

    file = open(path+files[2], encoding='utf8')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(file, features='lxml')
    for item in bs.find_all('item'):
        for ID, name, description, foto in zip(item.find_all('id'), item.find_all('name'), item.find_all('description'),
                                               item.find_all('id_foto')):
            print(ID)
            styles[i].update({'id': ID.string,
                              'description': description.string,
                              'name': name.string,
                              'foto': foto.string})
        i += 1
    return styles



print(parse_bd())
```

Полагаю, что проблема в том, что в этом куске xml-я есть символ переноса строки в description

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Style>
  <Item>
    <ID>66a0f87a-6b5c-4363-91c6-05098af05b43</ID>
    <Name>Bachata</Name>
    <Description>Бачата — невероятно красивый танец. Его гипнотизирующие ритмы наполнены чувственностью и романтикой, а движения танцоров грациозны и пластичны. Этот танец напоминает первый поцелуй, такой же нежный, и одновременно страстный и многообещающий… 
      В Латинской Америке бачата - танец очень популярный, его танцуют везде, на всех праздниках и танцплощадках. Звуки музыки передают акустическая, карибская гитара и бонго. Бачата — это яркий характер музыки и движений.
      Бачата - танец парный и танцевать его — непередаваемое удовольствие. В этом танце нужно слиться с музыкой и «почувствовать» партнера, стать с ним единым целым.
      Уроки бачаты - прекрасный способ сделать походку и движения красивыми, а фигуру — подтянутой и стройной. Обучение бачате доступно человеку любого возраста, веса и телосложения. Посещая уроки бачаты вы улучшаете координацию движений и получаете удовольствие от романтичного танца.
      Танец бачата остро чувственный, интимный, раскрепощенный! Женщинам  он помогает обрести женственность, грациозность, пластичность, а мужчинам – их исконное предназначение лидера, играющего ведущую роль в паре.</Description>
    <ID_Foto>97d1bd67-c5b2-478e-986a-618da2861e46</ID_Foto>
  </Item>
```

Как заставить BS корректно работать с этими символами? Гугление результатов не принесло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не будет в символе переноса строки в `description`.

Проблема будет с неправильными тегами в файле `Style.xml`. Кроме того, вы применяете **не** xml-parser, но **html-parser**:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(file, features="lxml")
```

Да, `"lxml"` не xml-parser. Используйте

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(file, features="lxml-xml")
```

или просто

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(file, features="xml")
```

---

*Примечание:*

Здесь пример неправильного XML-документа (см. теги `<tag1>`, `</tag2>`):

```
<root>
 <tag1>
 </tag2>
</root>
```

После применения `"lxml"`:

> ```
> <html>
>  <body>
>   <root>
>    <tag1>
>    </tag1>
>   </root>
>  </body>
> </html>
> ```

И после применения `"lxml-xml"`или `"xml"`:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <root>
>  <tag1/>
> </root>
> ```